# XmlPullParserException expected with Ksoap2

Tags: java, android, ksoap2

I encounter a lot of difficulty when using a Soap request in my android app. I use Ksoap2 library. I already created a post about it where you can see my code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51259280/android-use-a-ksoap2-request-with-https)

I try modify my constant like this:

```
public final static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/USER/WSS_USER_CLI/GETARTICLE/";
public final static String NAME_SPACE = "http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/USER/WSS_USER_CLI/GETARTICLE";
public final static String URL = "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1443/orawsv/USER/WSS_USER_CLI/GETARTICLE?wsdl";
public final static String GET_ARTICLE_METHOD_NAME = "GETARTICLE";
public final static String GET_ARTICLE_SOAP_ACTION = SOAP_ACTION + GET_ARTICLE_METHOD_NAME;
```

But now I have this error message:

```
> 07-13 11:17:33.163 3355-4210/com.ablinfo.mweb W/System.err: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <definitions name='GETARTICLE' targetNamespace='http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/USER/WSS_USER_CLI/GETARTICLE'>@6:56 in java.io.InputStreamReader@b3b2c69) 
07-13 11:17:33.164 3355-4210/com.ablinfo.mweb W/System.err:     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.require(KXmlParser.java:2065)
        at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:128)
        at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:129)
        at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.parseResponse(HttpTransportSE.java:301)
        at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:274)
        at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:118)
        at com.ablinfo.mweb.service.WebServiceCall.callWSThreadSoapPrimitive(WebServiceCall.java:62)
        at com.ablinfo.mweb.service.GetArticleTask.doInBackground(GetArticleTask.java:36)
07-13 11:17:33.165 3355-4210/com.ablinfo.mweb W/System.err:     at com.ablinfo.mweb.service.GetArticleTask.doInBackground(GetArticleTask.java:11)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: I have also same problem ,you can see my complete answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51255957/soap-request-creation-using-ksoap2-for-multilevel-tags/51340332#51340332

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I try to use httpClient but I have the error ": Error sending SOAP request
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed. "
I think this problem is with HTTPS. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How can I check my Parameters are correct for the SOAP? I Think my values of NAMESPACE, ACTION, METHOD and URL are wrong.

Comment: if you want to use my way of coding then you have to simply use library  httpclient and httpcore  and ksoap2 android library ...
and for the soapAction and url you can check your xml or you can discuss with your backened team..they will tell you exactly what should be SoapAction and URL should ..
you have to simply follow my way of coding and you will surely get the result.

Comment: I posted my code following your way of coding.